# Is there any free ASP.NET MVC Rich Text Editor with the ability to add Code Snippets?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, text-editor, code-snippets

I have an ASP.NET MVC application and I would need a Rich Text Editor which allows the user to add Code Snippets for HTML, JavaScript and C# codes.

Remember how Visual Studio formats such codes in term of indentation and colors. It doesn't have to be exact like what Visual Studio does but I mean just something that makes the reading of such codes easier for the user.

Something like a Syntax Highlighter for a Rich Text Editor.

Is there any free component that I could use?

I found this Rails plugin for CKEditor but it's not free: https://github.com/galetahub/rails-ckeditor

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Quick google search, MVC helpers for CKEditor:
http://www.andrewbarber.com/post/CKEditor-Html-Helpers-ASPNET-MVC-Razor-Views.aspx

Comment: CK Editor is beautiful! After fighting with tinymce for half a day, I got ckeditor running in less than 30 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly use the ASP.Net Ajax control toolkits HTML editor or third party tools.

Following is the link to HTML editor that you might be already knowing;

- http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/HTMLEditor/HTMLEditor.aspx
- http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/HTMLEditorExtender/HTMLEditorExtender.aspx
- http://mvccontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/
- http://richtexteditor.com/mvc/

Answer (score 2):

http://www.obout.com is free for non commercial website.

Comment: thanks but I don't see the Code Snippets feature? http://www.obout.com/Obout.Ajax.UI/HTMLEditor/examples/Content_FullHtml.aspx

Comment: Can you give us an example of what kind of Snipped you want to Add ?

Comment: HTML code, JavaScript code and C# Code. Have you seen how Visual Studio formats such codes in term of indentation and colors? It doesn't have to be exact like what Visual Studio does but I mean just something that makes the reading of such codes easier for the user.

Comment: Hum ok but I Think the displaying colors/indent etc... must be handled by your page rendering system not by the HTML Editor.
Like in Stackoverflow you select a bbcode in the Editor and the colors/indent etc.. are set when the post is rendered by the page.

Comment: I hoped it could be something like custom buttons on a Rich Text Editor which enables me to add such codes easily. This could be an example for C# code: http://pooyakhamooshi.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/how-to-instantiate-generic-type-with.html

Comment: Something like SyntaxHighlighter: http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/manual/demo/

Comment: I think you can find a jQuery plugin which handle this